# Consulta sobre buen uso del async/await

Tags: javascript, promesas, async-await

Tengo dudas si estoy usando bien las promesas con async/await, no se si es correcto usarlas de este modo, les quería preguntar si hay manera de simplificar el código o escribirlo le diferente modo, esta es una práctica para ver si se ejecutaba y lo hace bien solo no se si también se puede escribir de diferente modo.
Espero me ayuden a comprender mejor su funcionamiento, muchas gracias a todos.

```
 async function resolveCompras(){
    console.log('Compras de la semana...');
    const compra1 = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(''), 2000));
    console.log(compra1);
    const compra2 = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() =>  resolve(''), 2000));
    console.log(compra2);
    const compra3 = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() =>  resolve(''), 2000));
    console.log(compra3);
    const compra4 = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() =>  resolve(''), 2000));
    console.log(compra4);
    const compra5 = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(''), 2000));
    console.log(compra5);
    const pago = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() =>  resolve(''), 2000));
    console.log(pago);
}

resolveCompras();
```

Comment: No creo que un *dummy scenario*  sea lo más indicado para preguntar... Sí, funciona, y a efectos prácticos lo único que cambiaría sería sacar una función que resuelva la `Promise`, pero siendo un ejemplo tan sencillo... No tiene mucha relevancia hablar sobre él. Por otra parte, esto no es una comunidad de revisión de código. Salut (:

Answer (score 4):

Como va?

Mira la mejor manera siempre de optimizar la escritura del código para mi en lo casos donde tengo que repetir mucho código prefiero codear una función que le pase los parámetros variables y me devuelva lo que necesito.

En tu caso tenemos, que todas las compras
--retornan una promesa
--se ingresa un item
--se tarda un tiempo (hice que pueda ser variable para mejor legibilidad)

Entonces sabiendo esto ya sabemos la función que necesitamos codear

```js
//Creamos una funcion generar compras que recibe dos parametros
// 1 - el item
// 2 - el tiempo que se tarda
const generarCompras = (item , tiempo = 2000) => {

//Retornamos una promesa con un timeout con el tiempo indicado en el parametro
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve(item);
        },tiempo);
    })
}
```

Con esto ya tenemos nuestra función creada para crear cuantas compras queramos
así que dentro de tu función te quedaría así:

```js
async function resolveCompras(){

    console.log('Compras de la semana...');

    const compra1 = await generarCompras('');
    console.log(compra1);

    const compra2 = await generarCompras('');
    console.log(compra2);

    const compra3 = await generarCompras('');
    console.log(compra3);
    
    const compra4 = await generarCompras('');
    console.log(compra4);
    
    const compra5 = await generarCompras('');
    console.log(compra5);
  
    const pago = await generarCompras('')
    console.log(pago);
}

resolveCompras();
```

Espero haberte ayudado!